# Elmah - Download Log Is Empty

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I recently started using Elmah on our ASP.NET site and it's great however I've run into a problem.  Although my log contains plenty of errors (220 to be exact) and I can view them with the web viewer and rss, when I click Donwload Log it simply downloads an empty csv.  There is one row for the headers, but no rows!

Has this happened to anyone else?  Any ideas where to find the errors from within my error log?

Answer (score 0):

This [used to be a bug](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=82) in BETA 3 of version 1.0. Make sure you are using the [1.0 release](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.0-bin.zip) and not a pre-release.